# Consola Chrome POST jquery 404 (no encontrado): jquery.min.js:4

Tags: laravel

Holaa, tengo una función para cambiar la foto de perfil y al ejecutar en localhost en el navegador me esta saliendo este error en la consola POST jquery 404 (no encontrado): jquery.min.js:4. Alguien tiene una idea de como solucionarlo? Estuve viendo las rutas, pero no me resulto, sigue sin funcionar y no se como solucionarlo. Cualquier ayudita me vendría bien.

mi archivo .blade

```
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Croppie css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome 5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Actualizar perfil</h5>
            <div class="profile-img p-3">
                <img src="{{ asset('/images/icon-cam.png') }}" id="profile-pic">
            </div>
            <div class="btn btn-dark">
                <input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file-upload" 
                name="profile_picture" accept="image/*">
                Seleccionar nueva foto
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-content">                
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark" id="upload" >Continuar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<!--  jQuery and Popper.js  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Boostrap 4 -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Croppie js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.min.js"></script>
{{-- archivo js --}}
<script src="{{ asset ('photo/js.js') }}"></script>
```

Este es mi controlador

```
public function showJqueryImageUpload() 
{
    return view('demos.jqueryimageupload');
}

public function saveJqueryImageUpload(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'profile_picture' => 'required|image|max:1000',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return $validator->errors();            
    }

    $status = "";


    if ($request->hasFile('profile_picture')) {
        $image = $request->file('profile_picture');
        $filename = time().'.'.$image->guessExtension();

        $path = $request->file('profile_picture')->storeAs(
             'profile_picture', $filename
        );

        $status = "uploaded";            
    }

    return response($status,200);
}
```

y este mi archivo js con la funcion

```
$("#upload").on("click", function() {
    croppie.result('base64').then(function(base64) {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide"); 
        $("#profile-pic").attr("src","/images/ajax-loader.gif");

        var url = "{{url('demos/jquery-image-upload')}}";
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("profile_picture", $.base64ImageToBlob(base64));

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {  
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "uploaded") {
                    $("#profile-pic").attr("src", base64); 
                } else {
                    $("#profile-pic").attr("src","/images/icon-cam.png"); 
                    console.log(data['profile_picture']);
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                $("#profile-pic").attr("src","/images/icon-cam.png"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('demos/jquery-image-upload','DemoController@showJqueryImageUpload');
Route::post('demos/jquery-image-upload','DemoController@saveJqueryImageUpload');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
..................................................................

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar tu archivo routes?, porfavor

Comment: Es necesario que muestres tu archivo de rutas.

Comment: El archivo routes es un archivo php que se localiza en la dirección `routes/web.php` que nos servirá para distinguir hacia a donde dirige la ruta `demos/jquery-image-upload`

Comment: ok, lo agregue abajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione el problema, ahora funciona correctamente sin devolver el error 500 (Internal Server Error) en la consola del navegador. Lo que hice fue cambiar la funcion saveJqueryImageUpload en mi controlador.

```
public function saveJqueryImageUpload(Request $request)
{
    $status = "";

    $this->validate($request, [
        'profile_picture' => 'required|image:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('profile_picture'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('profile_picture');
        $ext = $image->guessExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$ext;

        $path = $request->file('profile_picture')->storeAs(
            'profile_pictures', $filename
        );

        $status = "uploaded"; 
    }        

    return response($status,200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error está en que estás usando un helper de laravel en el lugar equivocado, verás, todo lo que esté dentro de `{{  }}` es código que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, por lo tanto, un archivo `.js` se ejecuta del lado del cliente, entonces, tu variable `url` tendrá como valor la cadena de texto: `{{url('demos/jquery-image-upload')}}` literalmente. Para poder usar la ruta tendrías que declararla en el archivo `blade.php` como lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "{{ url('demos/jquery-image-upload') }}";
</script>

{{-- archivo js --}}
<script src="{{ asset ('photo/js.js') }}"></script>
```

No olvides eliminar la parte de asignación de valor en el archivo `js` una vez que la agregues en el archivo `blade`.

No es muy buena práctica tener variables globales, pero es un ejemplo de como debes de incrustar el valor en el archivo `blade`. También te recomendaría fuertemente asignarle alias a tus rutas con el método `name`:

```
Route::get('demos/jquery-image-upload','DemoController@showJqueryImageUpload')->name('image.upload.get');

Route::post('demos/jquery-image-upload','DemoController@saveJqueryImageUpload')->name('image.upload.post');
```

Y cuando requieras de alguna puedes usar el helper `route()` en vez del helper `url()`, ya que así evitas cambiar código en tus vistas si tu url necesita cambiar:

```
var url = "{{ route('image.upload.post') }}";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Otra consulta, ¿cuál seria la forma correcta de declarar la variable global en mi .blade? estuve probando y no me toma luego en mi archivo js

Comment: Lo agregué en un script, pero ahora me da error 500 (Internal Server Error) en la consola del navegador

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte Olvidé poner la variable `url` entre etiquetas `<script></script>` no sé si tu si lo pusiste correctamente. Ya lo corregí

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte Con respecto al error 500, ¿en tu html si está la etiqueta meta que contiene el token?, es decir, la siguiente: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`.

Comment: si, coloque el url en las etiquetas script, y si, también tengo agregado la etiqueta con el token, pero igual me sale el error 500 :c

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte Intenta subir una imagen muy ligera, que no pase del MB.

Comment: ya agregue la captura...

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte ¿Has verificado si los datos llegan a la primera línea del método del controlador al que llamas?

Comment: como puedo verificar eso?